# Applying a correlation measure to a split data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, correlation

I have split a data frame and output is as:

```
<code>
$'317'
Unique.ID    Start.Year   Risk      Gross Amount of loss
 317           2003       Type1        2000
 317           2014       Type1        3000
 317           2015       Type3         50

$'213'
Unique.ID    Start.Year   Risk      Gross Amount of loss
 213           2008       Type3        1000
 213           2011       Type1        3000
 213           2015       Type3         500
</code>
```

I would like to apply separately Kendall's tau to calculate correlations for each unique ID. (a unique ID is an identifier for a company and I have many companies) For example, for the last `Unique.ID` 317, I want to create a time series (using the `start.year` column) for each Risk (type 1, type2, type 3), and then calculate the correlation between each risk category using the Kendall Tau method and output in a matrix form such as this:

```
<code>

Unique ID: 317
            Type 1     Type 2     Type 3
Type 1       1            0         0.5
Type 2       0            1          0
Type 3       0.5          0          1

</code>
```

I am stuck in terms of coding, the above and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can apply a (any) function on each element of your list independently (you've got a list where each item correspond to a unique ID) with `lapply`

Comment: How do you get cor(Type 1,Type 3) = 0.5?

Comment: It is a random matrix whose purpose was just to illustrate what I wanted to output.